# Why available disk space is increased after copy a file?

Tags: linux, storage, nfs, network-attached-storage, storage-spaces

I was coping a file (`win2016.tar.gz`, 308.2GB) from ESXi host (`/vmfs/volumes/vmstore`) to a NFS datastore (`/vmfs/volumes/vmnfs`, share from my NAS ext4 partition).

```
[root@esxi:/vmfs/volumes] ls -lah vmstore/win2016.tar.gz
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root      308.2G Nov 12 13:52 vmstore/win2016.tar.gz
```

The NFS has 335.3G available space:

```
[root@esxi:/vmfs/volumes] df -h
Filesystem   Size   Used Available Use% Mounted on
NFS          3.6T   3.3T    335.3G  91% /vmfs/volumes/vmnfs
VMFS-5     907.8G 488.4G    419.3G  54% /vmfs/volumes/vmstore
#...
```

Copy the file to NFS datastore:

```
[root@esxi:/vmfs/volumes] cp vmstore/win2016.tar.gz vmnfs/tar/
```

While coping, I use `df` to check the available space few times, find out the available space is increasing:

```
[root@esxi:/vmfs/volumes] df -h
Filesystem   Size   Used Available Use% Mounted on
NFS          3.6T   3.1T    510.7G  86% /vmfs/volumes/vmnfs
VMFS-5     907.8G 488.4G    419.3G  54% /vmfs/volumes/vmstore
#...
[root@esxi:/vmfs/volumes] df -h
Filesystem   Size   Used Available Use% Mounted on
NFS          3.6T   3.1T    517.2G  86% /vmfs/volumes/vmnfs
VMFS-5     907.8G 488.4G    419.3G  54% /vmfs/volumes/vmstore
#...
[root@esxi:/vmfs/volumes] df -h
Filesystem   Size   Used Available Use% Mounted on
NFS          3.6T   3.1T    537.4G  85% /vmfs/volumes/vmnfs
VMFS-5     907.8G 488.4G    419.3G  54% /vmfs/volumes/vmstore
#...
```

After I checked the file `/vmfs/volumes/vmnfs/tar/win2016.tar.gz` is growing, I went to sleep.

When finished copy, I check the disk space again:

```
[root@esxi:/vmfs/volumes] df -h
Filesystem   Size   Used Available Use% Mounted on
NFS          3.6T   3.1T    487.7G  87% /vmfs/volumes/vmnfs
VMFS-5     907.8G 488.4G    419.3G  54% /vmfs/volumes/vmstore
```

The available space is decreased compare to the value when the file is coping (537.4 -> 487.7). But I still get 487.7 - 335.3 = 152.4GB 'free up' after copy a 308.2GB file.

Why I get 'more available space' after copy a file?
I guess this is related to how linux calculate disk space?

Comment: Did somebody delete something else?

Comment: No, I am the only one using the NAS. I did not delete anything when coping the file but I delete something before the copy.

Comment: Exactly what NAS is it?

Comment: asustor as604t, with raid 1

Comment: Did you overwrite a file on the NFS share that had a bigger size?

Comment: No, the `tar` directory is created just before the copy.